# Pass values in birt template

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, pdf, birt

I have to work for the first time with birt and have template (.rptdesign) and want to add the values from the java program and export is as pdf. my data is stored in collections. i did a lot of research but so far, i haven't found a way to write the data into the template.
my code to do this is

```
IReportEngine engine = null;
EngineConfig config = null;

config = new EngineConfig();
config.setBIRTHome(System.getProperty("user.dir")+File.separator+
"reports"+ File.separator+"tickets-without-hours.rptdesign");

Platform.startup(config);
IReportEngineFactory factory = (IReportEngineFactory) 
Platform.createFactoryObject(IReportEngineFactory.
EXTENSION_REPORT_ENGINE_FACTORY);
engine = factory.createReportEngine(config);

IReportRunnable design = null;

design = engine.openReportDesign("path/name.rptdesign");
IRunAndRenderTask task = engine.createRunAndRenderTask(design);


PDFRenderOption options = new PDFRenderOption();
options.setOutputFileName(path);
options.setOutputFormat("pdf");

task.setRenderOption(options);
task.run();
task.close();
engine.destroy();
```

My problem is that i don't know how i can pass my data into the template. I only get a pdf document with two plank pages.
Thanks for your help, Marina